# ¿Se puede usar la función sample_n () en una sola declaración para obtener varias muestras aleatorias con tamaño variable?

Tags: r, function, r-dplyr, tidyverse

Espero esten bien. He buscado en internet y no he dado con la solución a mi problema. Yo tengo un vector de caracteres de 451 individuos, y lo que quisiera sería elegir al azar, sin reemplazo y de forma creciente muestras de esos 451 individuos. Este sería como un ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo, pero quisiera saber si es posible crear un ciclo o una función que permita extraer las muestras usando la función sample_n() u otra función similar sin necesidad de usarla varias veces? Y si es posible, a partir del enfoque del tidyverse. Les estaré muy agradecido cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar. Un feliz día.

```r
Pob_IND_2 <- c('Leonardo', 'Luis', 'Juan', 'Jonatan', 'Camilo', 'Paola') %>%
  as_tibble()

a <- Pob_IND_2 %>%
  sample_n(size = 2)

b <- Pob_IND_2 %>%
  sample_n(size = 4)

c <- Pob_IND_2 %>%
  sample_n(size = 6)
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: Good morning, you asked on stackoverflow spanish, I recommend to you to ask on stackoverflow english

Comment: Disculpen, no me habia dado cuenta. Ya realice el cambio al español. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas de resolverlo, por ejemplo, partiendo de un vector que establezca la cantidad de valores para cada muestra:

```
samples <- c(2,1,2,3,4,1) # Generamos 6 muestras con distintas cantidades

lista <- lapply(samples, FUN = function(x) sample_n(Pob_IND_2, x)
```

Aplicamos `sample_n` sobre los datos y con el valor de cantidad del vector `samples`, con lo que terminamos con una lista de 6 `tibbles` que podemos acceder así:

```
lista[[1]]
lista[[6]]
```